# Trying to launch a URL in browser from my flutter app. When I click the button I created to launch the URL nothing happens. Don't know why

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create an app that allows the user to click a button and have a website open in their browser. I wrote this code with a lot of help from the Flutter docs. Everything compiles and runs fine but when I click the button in the middle of the screen that is supposed to launch the URL nothing happens. The button just does what I think is a splash animation but the URL is not launched in the browser as intended. This doesn't have anything to do with the fact that I am using an emulator to test this does it? Or is a problem with the url_launcher package? I will attach my code and the .yaml file. Would appreciate any response from anyone. Thank you very much!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Your Covid-19 Briefing"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: _launchUrl,
            child: Text("Covid-19 Cases"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _launchUrl() async {
    const _urlToLaunch = "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/";
    if (await canLaunch(_urlToLaunch)) {
      await launch(_urlToLaunch);
    } else {
      throw "Could not open $_urlToLaunch";
    }
  }
}

name: coronavirus_news_updates
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  url_launcher: ^5.4.11


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
```

Comment: Does the emulator have browser apps?

Comment: I believe it does. You can access the google browser from the emulator. So to me that indicates that it should be working.

Answer (score 0):

Does it throw any error?. I tried running the above code with both emulator and my smartphone and it works fine.

Comment: No error is thrown. The code complies fine but when I click the button that is supposed to open the browser nothing happens.